# Are these 2 private LAN IP addresses on the same subnet or are in different subnets?

Tags: networking, ip, lan, subnet

I am not so into networking and I have the following doubt related to some machines into the network of a customer.

So I have the following situation.

- MACHINE 1: 10.173.17.92
- MACHINE 2: 10.173.21.80

These should be two private LAN addresses.

Both start with **10.173** but the third segment of these 2 addresses is different (**17** and **21**).

So my doubt is: are these 2 IPs on the same subnet or could be in different subnet?

Comment: Yes they are on different sub nets.

Comment: You are not giving us enough information to answer this question... The IP address by itself is not sufficient to determine the size of the network and the range it covers. These could very well be in the same subnet, or could be totally unique, but without knowing the subnet mask associated with these IP's it would be impossible to definitively answer this question.

Comment: @Moab They could be on the same subnet. The OP hasn't provided the netmask,

Comment: You can only say that if you know the submask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided enough information to answer your question.  You need to tell us the network mask for each address.  That will determine if the addresses are on the same subnet or not.

> Both start with 10.173 but the third segment of these 2 addresses is different (17 and 21).

Do not be confused by similar "segments." You can't infer the subnet from them.  Remember that IP addresses are 32-bit binary numbers (that's how your computer sees them).  To your computer, the address 10.173.17.92 is 000010101010110000010001001011100.

We write the address using the dotted decimal notation to make it easier for us humans to read.  The dots in the address have no significance to the computer -- they're just there for your convenience.